# Which first character would be the best to make to 'get rich quick', aside from Sorceress?

Tags: diablo-ii-resurrected

The Sorceress is players', including myself, most frequent go-to character when starting out a new ladder, mainly because of the character's ability to teleport, making it able to magic find (mf) faster.  It also has a great skill tree and good end-game potential.

For people trying to mix things up in the upcoming 2.4 ladder, considering all the balance changes that will come into play, what would be the best alternative character/build if the goal is to either forge your own Enigma or trade for one?

Answer (score 2):

[Currently the Assassin is the next-best class, followed by Paladin/Amazon/Druid.](https://d2.maxroll.gg/tierlists/solo-speedrun-tier-list)

> considering all the balance changes

This, on the other hand, is unknowable until the balance changes are actually live.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Huh? Can whoever left that comment explain why it's unclear?

Comment: One way to improve this answer is to summarize the link content. This is important for answers since the link content may change or vanish.

Comment: @AmyB I did summarize the link content. Assassin is the next-best class, followed by Paladin/Amazon/Druid.

Comment: this seems to be purely from a speedrunning perspective though.  Not sure if it helps me with my end goal, if so, can you explain how?

Comment: @Traceur your goal is to "get rich quick" right? If so then that's effectively the same as "complete Hell difficulty" since you need to complete Hell difficulty to get rich. I don't understand your question, it seems very unusual.

Comment: @Allure I'm sorry but completing Hell and 'getting rich' are not the same at all.  You can have a Sorceress that doesn't even go to Hell and just farms NM act bosses for gear and trades her way up to end-game gear

Comment: @Traceur you could certainly do that, but it's not ideal. https://www.mmobux.com/articles/404/how-to-get-rich-quick-in-diablo-2-resurrected "Don’t waste time farming on the normal difficulty. If you are playing solo, collect what you need and get through the storyline. It will be more challenging at first, but the increase in rewards will speed up your ability to build wealth ten-fold. The same goes for Hell mode, but you’ll find rushing through Nightmare a bit more difficult."